# How to ignore violation of primary key constraint in linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, exception

I have a table where both fields (`idLocation, zipcode`) are used as the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[locationZipCode](
    [idLocation] [int] NOT NULL,
    [zipcode] [char](5) NOT NULL,
    [state] [char](2) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [locationZipCode_pk_idLocation_zipcode] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([idLocation], [zipcode])
 )
```

In my app I'm calling:

```
context.InsertAllOnSubmit(entities);
context.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
```

And getting a duplicate key violation when duplicate records are attempted to be inserted. This is expected. If any records are duplicate then no records are inserted.  **Is there anyway to ignore duplicate key exceptions and continue inserting any records that don't violate primary key constraints?**

I realize I can validate duplication before calling `InsertAllOnSubmit()` in my app but it would be ideal if I could just catch the error and just continue with the inserts.

Comment: Loop through the entities and call insert and submit for each one.  You can catch and handle the error yourself then.  It still sounds like a terrible idea.  Validate your input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For SQL Server `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` flag makes database engine ignore key violations. Nothing changes in DB if key exists.

```
 CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [locationZipCode_idx] ON locationZipCode
 (
    [idLocation] ASC, [zipcode] ASC
 ) WITH ( IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON )
```

Don't forget to remove current PK first.

Comment: I don't think OP wants to insert duplicates, he just wants to not insert them.

Comment: @cadrell0 This is exactly what this sql does. No duplicates, no errors on 2-nd and next inserts of the same key.

Comment: @Anri My bad, I didn't look at the documentation.

Comment: @bflemi3 because it's little faster this way. CLUSTERED index means the physical order of the rows in table will be the same as the index order is. You can skip this keyword.